# What does this react native init code mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

What does this code actually mean?

```
var React = require('react-native');
var {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    Image,
    View,
    } = React;
```

I know the `React` is a module imported by node, Does it copy the `React` object to the list above?

And I added the

`var {Image} = React;`

it works too. I'm new to Node.js and React and get confused.

[SOLVED] by Ramanlfc:
This is a **destructing assignment**:

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that
>   makes it possible to extract data from arrays or objects using a
>   syntax that mirrors the construction of array and object literals.

Comment: it's destructing  assignment : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by [Ramanlfc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542124/what-does-this-react-native-init-code-mean#comment56826135_34542124) in the comments; it is the [ECMAScript 2015 **Destructuring** assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax.

Essentially that statement

```
var {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    Image,
    View,
} = React;
```

is the equivalent of

```
var AppRegistry = React.AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet = React.StyleSheet,
    Text = React.Text,
    Image = React.Image,
    View = React.View;
```

It's an easier way of assigning object properties to variables of the same name;